# In Pandas, how to return 2 data using resample('D').first()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Questions

- Q1. Why does the `float` data changes to `string` data when it gets put into a `pd.dataframe`? Is there any way to keep it float, rather than changing it to float afterwards with `.astype(float)`?
- Q2. How to get 2 data using `resample('D').first()` method? The method `.first()` returns only 1 data, while I want 2 data to be returnd. : If it is not possible with `.first()` method, can you give me an alternative solution?

### Code Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

BTC_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.05,'BTC'],[1.2,'BTC'],[0.9,'BTC']]),
                      columns = ['return','coin'],
                      index = [datetime(2020,5,1,15), datetime(2020,5,2,9,20), datetime(2020,5,3,23,40)])

ETH_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.1,'ETH'],[0.9,'ETH'],[0.95,'ETH']]),
                      columns = ['return','coin'],
                      index = [datetime(2020,5,1,8,30), datetime(2020,5,2,17,30), datetime(2020,5,3,11,50)])

EOS_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.3,'EOS'],[0.6,'EOS'],[0.8,'EOS']]),
                      columns = ['return','coin'],
                      index = [datetime(2020,5,1,1,20), datetime(2020,5,2,22,10), datetime(2020,5,3,13,5)])

BTC_df
>>>                  return  coin
2020-05-01 15:00:00   1.05   BTC
2020-05-02 09:20:00   1.2    BTC
2020-05-03 23:40:00   0.9    BTC

##############################################
# Q1. Why does the 'float' changes to 'str'? #
##############################################
BTC_df.loc[datetime(2020,5,2,9,20),'return']
>>>   '1.2'

merged_df = pd.concat([BTC_df,ETH_df,EOS_df])
merged_df.loc[:,'return'] = merged_df.loc[:,'return'].astype(float)  # from 'str' to 'float'
merged_df.loc[:,'time'] = merged_df.index.time  # to preserve hour and minutes

#################################################################
# Q2. How to create the 'desired output' using resample method? #
#################################################################
merged_df.resample('D').first()
>>>        return  coin     time
2020-05-01  1.30    EOS   01:20:00
2020-05-02  1.20    BTC   09:20:00
2020-05-03  0.95    ETH   11:50:00
```

My desired output is as follows, showing 2 coins with the earliest time :

```
desired_output_df
>>>         return  coin    time
2020-05-01  1.30    EOS   01:20:00
            1.10    ETH   08:30:00
2020-05-02  1.20    BTC   09:20:00
            0.90    ETH   17:30:00
2020-05-03  0.95    ETH   11:50:00
            0.80    EOS   13:05:00
```

Comment: +1 and congrats on this perfectly formulated question - I wish all questions were prepared this way with directly runnable examples and clear questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: this is because you defined the whole data as **one** array, which can have one type only for all data (string). Define it columnwise like so:

```
BTC_df = pd.DataFrame({'return': [1.05, 1.2, 0.9], 'coin': ['BTC', 'BTC', 'BTC']},
                      index = [datetime(2020,5,1,15), datetime(2020,5,2,9,20), datetime(2020,5,3,23,40)])
```

Q2: use

```
merged_df.resample('D').apply(lambda x: x[:2])
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of your answer code? What does the code`.apply(lambda x: x[:2])` mean? It works perfectly, but I am curious to know the meaning of it.

Comment: Resample returns a series for each resample moment. We take the first two elements of the series (0 and 1). (`first()` is equivalent to `apply(lambda x: x[0])`), see also example #7 in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)